# Easy way to switch between logged in user to test different accounts

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension

I used to use [cookieswap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookieswap/) in firefox to help when developing a website where different user accounts had different options selected - the easiest way I've found to switch quickly which user you're logged in as.

As far as I can see there isn't a similar extension for chrome, but is there some other clever dev tool/approach I can use to facilitate easy user-switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up multiple user profiles in Chrome under chrome://settings > Users.

Or open a new incognito window and log in under your desired account?